# Scalatra Servlet init() during test (Jetty ServletTester)

Tags: unit-testing, scala, servlets, initialization, scalatra

I am testing a Scalatra servlet that does some important initialization in its `init(context: ServletContext)` method.

During tests (with [ScalatraSuite](http://www.scalatra.org/guides/testing.html)) that `init` is not executed.
How should I do my *important* initialization when I am testing?

That [Scalatra testing page](http://www.scalatra.org/guides/testing.html) (section "Testing FAQ") does not reveal that.

**Extra Info:**
The "Testing FAQ" section states

> scalatra-test is built on Jetty's [ServletTester][3]

but I also could not extract any information from the internet on how to run the init if I were coding in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `servletContextHandler` for those things in a test.

You can set `initParameters` with `servletContextHandler.setInitParameter("the.param", "the.value")`

I'll update the docs so they won't say that the testing support is added through jetty tester.
In fact it uses an embedded jetty server so the `init` method should get called.